# JSP imported class implementation not resloving type

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting an exception when i have my jsp file on the webserver, it says the following:

```
    type Exception report

    message 

    description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception 

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
    Only a type can be imported. edu.byu.isys413.data.Customer resolves to a package

    An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /account.jsp
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    121:                                         <tr valign=top>
    122:                                             <td height=19></td>
    123:                                             <% if (session.getAttribute("customer") != null) {
    124:                                                     Customer c = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customer");%>
    125:                                             <td align="center"><%="Welcome " +      c.getFirstName() + "!"%></td>
    126:                                             <% }%>
    127:                                             <td height=19></td>


    An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /account.jsp
    Customer cannot be resolved to a type
    121:                                         <tr valign=top>
    122:                                             <td height=19></td>
    123:                                             <% if (session.getAttribute("customer") != null) {
    124:                                                     Customer c = (Customer) session.getAttribute("customer");%>
    125:                                             <td align="center"><%="Welcome " + c.getFirstName() + "!"%></td>
    126:                                             <% }%>
    127:                                             <td height=19></td>


    Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

And the jsp page look like

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01             Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
         <%@ page import="edu.Customer" %>
 <% if (session.getAttribute("customer") != null) {
                                                Customer c = (Customer)    session.getAttribute("customer");%>
 <td align="center"><%="Welcome " + c.getFirstName() + "!"%></td>
                                        <% }%>
```

I know a lot of people posted here the same problem, but Im certainly sure that the Customer.java is under /WEB-INF/classes/edu/Customer.java. So is there any other configuration problem here? I'm using IIS that connect to tomcat. I can get to the file alright, but I cant compile the JSP.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Im certainly sure that the Customer.java is under /WEB-INF/classes/edu/Customer.java.*

You need the compiled class file instead of the raw Java source file. So, you must have a `/WEB-INF/classes/edu/Customer.class`.

You can use `javac` to compile Java source files to class files. Or consider using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans when you've already a good grasp on manually building/compiling Java projects and a good understanding of the phenomenon "classpath". The IDE will then do it all automagically for you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to run javac command in cmd and it gives me javac is not recognized even after I set up the path to javac.exe. Do you happen to know where the problem is?